# Converting Date-Time to UNIX Time

Tags: r, unix, time

I'm hoping someone here knows what's going on. I'm having this strange issue where when I'm trying to convert some date/times to UNIX time I get negative numbers, here is my code for reference:

```
> foo <- '4/1/2017 00:02:23'
> alpha = as.POSIXct(foo)
> alpha
[1] "0004-01-20 LMT"
> beta = as.numeric(alpha)
> beta
[1] -62039347125 #Why?!?!?!
```

So basically, I go through the above and I end up with a negative number, the annoying thing is that no matter what date/Time I am using, I end up with the same result. The format of date/time is month/day/year hour:minute:second.

Does anyone know what's going on? Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you're using the year 4, that is, 1966 years before Unix time started. You should do:

```
foo <- '2017/4/1 00:02:23'
alpha = as.POSIXct(foo)
alpha

## "2017-04-01 00:02:23 EDT"

beta = as.numeric(alpha)
beta

## 1491019343
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not really in a position to change the format, but it's okay, I have found the 'format' argument which has solved my issue (see my answer). Thanks!!

Comment: Good! I was going to edit my post to tell you about `format`. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. You need to specify the format of the date time..

So:

```
> foo <- '4/1/2017 00:02:23'
> alpha = as.POSIXct(foo, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
> beta = as.numeric(alpha)
> beta
[1] 1491001343
```